# How to configure routing for a java web app

Tags: java, servlets, static, routes

Is there an easy way to rout all requests (except a few specific cases) for url "mysite/" to path "mysite/index.html?"
Is it possible to do it only by editing web.xml file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always have a list of welcome pages for directories (those shown if the URL requested maps to a directory).

If this is not enough you may want to look at servlet Filters, which can do all kinds of transformations.  http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/Filters.html

Answer (score 3):

Did you try to specify it as welcome file in your `web.xml`:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: Yes. this valie is specified... sorry, my message was modified: I want to redirect "mysite/some_key" to "mysite/index.html?some_key"